# Internet Explorer 11 http request has no data in response on first attempt

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, ssl

I have an endpoint in my app (endpoint A) that returns HTML/JS that should self-execute and hit another endpoint (endpoint B).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="link" href="https://myhost/mycontext/endpointB" />       
        <script language='javascript'>
            document.getElementById('link').click();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I launch endpoint A  in Chrome/Firefox/Safari, endpoint B correctly loads in the browser on the first attempt.

In Internet Explorer 11, however, it actually fails on the first request to navigate to endpoint B, and then inexplicably issues another request to endpoint A again.  On this second request to endpoint A, it successfully executes the JavaScript and loads endpoint B.

Fiddler indicates that an 'SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake' was found in the second request but not in the first request.  **Does this imply that my first request from IE does not have a compatible handshake for some reason?  What would cause this?  Is this a consequence of issuing the request from self-executing JavaScript?**

**Request 1 (Does not successfully launch endpoint B)**

```
CONNECT myhost:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: myhost
Pragma: no-cache

After the client received notice of the established CONNECT, it failed to send any data.
```

**Response 1 (no body)**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 11:37:20.457
Connection: close
```

**Request 2 (Successfully launches endpoint B)**

```
CONNECT myhost:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: myhost
Pragma: no-cache

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Version: 3.3 (TLS/1.2)
Random: 57 8F A8 C0 C7 95 85 02 77 14 1F 10 FD 10 D6 1E 67 2A DA F1 F6 27 22 45 55 FA 8D 55 0B 5D 6B 21
"Time": 6/4/2072 8:23:35 AM
SessionID: empty
Extensions: 
    server_name myhost
    status_request  OCSP - Implicit Responder
    elliptic_curves secp256r1 [0x17], secp384r1 [0x18]
    ec_point_formats    uncompressed [0x0]
    signature_algs  sha512_rsa, sha512_ecdsa, sha256_rsa, sha384_rsa, sha1_rsa, sha256_ecdsa, sha384_ecdsa, sha1_ecdsa, sha1_dsa
    extended_master_secret  empty
    renegotiation_info  00
Ciphers: 
    [C028]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C027]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [009F]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009E]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [009D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [009C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [003D]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [003C]  TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    [C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
    [C024]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
    [C023]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [C00A]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [C009]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [006A]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
    [0040]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION
```

**Response 2**

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 11:37:20.493
Connection: close

Encrypted HTTPS traffic flows through this CONNECT tunnel. HTTPS Decryption is enabled in Fiddler, so decrypted sessions running in this tunnel will be shown in the Web Sessions list.

Secure Protocol: Tls12
Cipher: Aes256 256bits
Hash Algorithm: Sha384 384bits
Key Exchange: ECDHE_RSA (0xae06) 256bits

== Server Certificate ==========
[Subject]
  CN=*.mycompanyname.com, OU=Secure Link SSL Wildcard, O=My Company's Name, STREET=My Address, L=My City, S=IL, PostalCode=99999, C=US

[Issuer]
  CN=Network Solutions OV Server CA 2, O=Network Solutions L.L.C., L=Herndon, S=VA, C=US

[Serial Number]
  Removed before posting to StackOverflow

[Not Before]
  8/13/2015 7:00:00 PM

[Not After]
  1/26/2017 5:59:59 PM

[Thumbprint]
  Removed before posting to StackOverflow

[SubjectAltNames]
*.mywebsite.com, mywebsite.com
```

Comment: You might want to close your anchor tag.

Comment: Thanks.  That was a copy/paste error.  I just confirmed that the anchor tag is properly closed in the real code.